# Xcode won't autocomplete enums within a switch statement in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, enums, switch-statement

Hi I'm having a bit of a problem using enums within a switch statement. The issue is that Xcode won't autocomplete and bring up the enum cases despite me using the dot notation within the switch statement.

[image]

Ive tried writing out the keyword favDay after the case keyword  before the dot notation and it won't bring up the enum cases. Ive even tried switching on the Days type as well but it still won't autocomplete.

Does anyone Know why this is happening? My macbook air is new and Ive had it for a month and Im using Xcode version 7.3.1

I get the autocomplete help with the enums cases outside of the switch statement and it works perfectly fine however it won't work inside a switch statement. However If I use a function and then use the switch statement it works perfectly fine however not when I'm using the switch statement on its own.

[image]

Im getting confused as it seems like you can only use enums and switch statements within a function but then the apple documentation shows enums and switch statements together without the use of ay functions.

Can anyone help me please its driving me mad. Have I accidentally changed a setting or something? It does this for all enums and switch statements that I've  tried to write that are not related to a function

Thank You for your help

Alia :)

Comment: I see this behavior in Xcode 8 as well.  Just seems like a limitation of Xcode.

Comment: A playground is special in that you can have executable code (the switch statement) outside of a function.  Since Xcode typically wouldn't expect to see a switch statement at global scope it seems it's just a bug with its parser. Good thing to file a radar on.

Comment: Thanks so its not me, thats reassuring to know

Comment: I too face this issue with Swift projects in Xcode. I basically counter this problem by building the project and then I am able to get suggestions in autocomplete.

Comment: @par — you're spot on; I just encountered this frustration with Xcode and it turns out that once I moved my test code out of global scope, my enum autocompleted as it should. Thanks!